# Find the exponential curve through three data points

Tags: calculus

I have the following data points:

$\{( 500, -0.6), (1000, -0.7),(2000, -0.8) \}$.

I'm trying to find the equation that will allow me to enter any x between 30 and 2000 and get y on the curve that passes through these three points.  I feel like this is quite simple and I've done it many times, but it's been too long since I've regularly used differentials, and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: What form is your desired exponential curve? If it's $y=k a^x$ you get 3 eqns 2 unknowns, would need best fit idea. Or if you add a constant to that there would be 3 eqns 3 unknowns and maybe a unique solution.

Comment: Best fit is what I was looking for.

Comment: This seems to be more of the form $x = ka^y$, not $y = ka^x$

Comment: In this case an exact fit is available. Glancing at the data, we see that an increase of $0.1$ in the $x$-coordinate results in a halving of the $y$-coordinate, so picking the first point as a reference point gives $y = 500 \cdot 2^{-(10 x + 6)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=ka^x,$ then taking logs gives $\log y=\log k + \log a \cdot x.$ So using the logs of the $x,y$ from points gives a standard linear regression. Most calculators, like TI type, can find numerical values. (only three points...)

Added: Just realized your $y$ values all negative. So maybe safer to change signs of $y$ values before proceeding as above, remembering to put the minus back at the end.

Another note: Your data isn't suggestive of exponential fit, even with an extra minus sign, since $y$ goes down by a constant amount when $x$ is doubled. That look more like some kind of shifted log curve. [with only 3 data points hard to say anything...]

Here is a formula based on above shifted log idea. Here $\lg(u)=\ln(u)/\ln(2),$ i.e. log base two.
$$y=-0.6+\lg(x/500) \cdot (-0.1).$$
Try it and see if it looks right for your app. It goes through your 3 points. At
$x=30$ it's about $-0.194.$

Answer (score 2):

[Find the exponential curve through three data points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311614/find-the-exponential-curve-through-three-data-points)

If you want to fit
$ae^{bx}+c$
to 3 points,
$(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^3$,
you want
$y_i=ae^{bx_i}+c
$.

Subtracting the first two,
$y_2-y_1
=a(e^{bx_2}-e^{bx_1})
=ae^{bx_1}(e^{b(x_2-x_1)}-1)
$
and,
similarly,
$y_3-y_2
=a(e^{bx_3}-e^{bx_2})
=ae^{bx_2}(e^{b(x_3-x_2)}-1)
$.

If
$x_3-x_2
=x_2-x_1
=d$,
so the data are
equally spaced
and
$e^{b(x_2-x_1)}-1
=e^{b(x_3-x_2)}-1
$,
we can divide these to get

$\dfrac{y_3-y_2}{y_2-y_1}
=e^{bx_2-bx_1}
=e^{b(x_2-x_1)}
=e^{bd}
$.

Taking logs,
and letting
$r = \dfrac{y_3-y_2}{y_2-y_1}
$,
$\ln(r)
=bd
$
so
$b = \dfrac{\ln(r)}{d}
$.
From this,
$e^b
=r^{1/d}
$.

Note that this requires that
$r > 0$,
so the points are monotonic.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
y_2-y_1
&=a(e^{bx_2}-e^{bx_1})\\
&=a(r^{x_2/d}-r^{x_1/d})\\
\end{array}
$

so that

$a
=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{r^{x_2/d}-r^{x_1/d}}
$.

We also get

$a
=\dfrac{y_3-y_2}{r^{x_3/d}-r^{x_2/d}}
=\dfrac{y_3-y_1}{r^{x_3/d}-r^{x_1/d}}
$.

Finally,
$c = y_i-ae^{bx_i}$
for any $i$.